# Show that $(\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z})[x]$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[x]\oplus\mathbb{Z}[x] $ .

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification

Problem says:

> Show that $(\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z})[x]$ is **not** isomorphic to
>   $\mathbb{Z}[x]\oplus\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

But consider the map $\varphi:(\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z})[x]\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}[x]\oplus\mathbb{Z}[x]$
  defined by $$(a_{m},b_{m})x^{m}+\cdots+(a_{1},b_{1})x+(a_{0},b_{0})\mapsto(a_{m}x^{m},b_{m}x^{m})+\cdots+(a_{1}x,b_{1}x)+(a_{0},b_{0})
 .$$

It seems a well-defined isomorphism between those rings. So, I think that problem is wrong. Is it okay?

Comment: $\sum_k (a_k,b_k) x^k$ is sent to $(\sum_k a_k x^k,\sum_k b_k x^k)$ and conversely. $ \ \ \ $

the addition is obviously compatible, and $$(\sum_k (a_k,b_k) x^k)(\sum_m (c_m,d_m) x^m) = \sum_k \sum_m x^{k+m} (a_k c_m,b_k d_m)$$ while $$(\sum_k a_k x^k,\sum_k b_k x^k)(\sum_m c_m x^m,\sum_m d_m x^m) = (\sum_k \sum_m x^{k+m} a_k c_m ,\sum_k \sum_m x^{k+m} b_k d_m)$$
hence the two rings are isomorphic